# Access to PCIe endpoint BAR through windows OS

Tags: express, driver, device, serial-communication, pci

I am studying the feasibility to communicate from a windows host with an endpoint device connected through a PCI express peripheral. Unfortunately my knowledge about PCI express is very low, so sorry in advance for the mitakes I will write.

If I understood well the PCI express specifications, the RC is using the "Base Address Register" addresses (seen as memory address from the CPU point of view) in order to write/read bytes to the endpoint device. Am I right ?
I am wondering how, if the RC is running on a windows OS host, we are supposed to write/read to these BAR. Do we need to write a kind of "device driver" or is there one already existing ? Is there any tool which would provide us the possibility to read/write to this "memory area" (something like this one : https://pypi.org/project/pyPCIe/) ?
Is it enough to setup a PCI express communication between a PC and an endpoint device ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, on x86 systems, the BARs represent physical system memory addresses. The region(s) need to be mapped to virtual addresses to access them. The registers  in the BAR region are device specific, so you need a device driver that is specific to the device to use them. A generic driver such as the one you linked could read or write  the raw registers, but it couldn't really do anything useful with them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer ! I will have a specific driver running on the endpoint device, but I was wondering how i can initiate the data transmission from the host PC. If the endpoint is seen after the enumeration process, would it be enough to write data to the address specified by the BAR register ? How is the memory mapping done in a windows os ? Sorry for such interrogations, examples for such usecase are rare and it is difficult to clearly see how it works just by reading specifications.